# javascript iterate through div changing the background colour

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to automatically change the background-color to a different background-color for each div, each div should have a different colour.

I'm not entirely sure why my html is not correctly displayed and why I get   [object HTMLCollection]

my HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <h3>box</h3>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

The function I use is:

```
bgColor(document.getElementById('box').getElementsByTagName('div'));

    function bgColor() {

      var tableCntr= document.getElementById('box');
      var tblHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

      var colors = [['red','blue','green'],['orange', 'black', 'purple']]  ;

        for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++) {

          for(var j=0;j<colors[0][0].length;j++) {
            tblHTML += "<div style='background:" + colors[i][j] + "'> </div>" ;
          }
       }
      tableCntr.innerHTML = tblHTML ;  
    }

    window.onload = bgColor;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rkceLv9/)

Comment: Why does your function not use the argument you're passing it? (Or: Why are you passing the function an argument it doesn't use?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not really sure, I really need to understand it better, that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: Can you explain it more.

Comment: @Sahadev the explanation is clear, I should use the argument that I'm passing. On my question I'm asking why my background colors are showing but the html is not correctly displayed, I guess my function is not correct.

Comment: `tblHTML` is an `[object HTMLCollection]` you can't add divs to it using `+=`. If you want to change the background of existing divs, you'll need to loop on this collection and change the style `style.background = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated....

```
function bgColor(ID) {

  var tableCntr= document.getElementById(ID);
  var DIVs = tableCntr.getElementsByTagName('div');

  var colors = ['red','blue','green','orange', 'black', 'purple']  ;

  var colourIndex = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<DIVs.length;i++) {

     DIVs[i].setAttribute('style','background-color: '+colors[colourIndex]);
     colourIndex = (colourIndex + 1) % colors.length;
  }
}

bgColor('box');
```

Comment: is it possible to pass this argument?  bgColor(document.getElementById('box').getElementsByTagName('div')); ?

Comment: sure. `function bgColor(DIVs)` and then uncomment the lines before `var colors`

Answer (score 1):

javascript solution, you dont need to pass agrumenst in the function bgColor();

```
    bgColor();
    function bgColor() {

    var tableCntr= document.getElementById('box');
    var tblHTML = '';//document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    var colors = [['red','blue','green'],['orange', 'black', 'purple']]  ;

     for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++) {
         for(var j=0;j<colors[0][0].length;j++) {
            tblHTML += "<div style='background:" + colors[i][j] + "'> </div>" ;
         }
     }
     tableCntr.innerHTML = '<h3>box</h3>'+tblHTML ;  
    }

   window.onload = bgColor;
```

jQuery Solution

```
bgColor();

 function bgColor() {

  var tableCntr = jQuery('#box');
  var tblHTML = '';
  var colors = [['red','blue','green'],['orange', 'black', 'purple']]  ;

    for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<colors[0][0].length;j++) {
        tblHTML += "<div style='background:" + colors[i][j] + "'> </div>" ;
      }
   }
  tableCntr.html( tblHTML );  
}

window.onload = bgColor;
```

Comment: I agree with @Oposyma something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8rkceLv9/2/

Comment: @Oposyma thanks, looks neat. Any chance I can use the argument bgColor(document.getElementById('box').getElementsByTagName('div'));  into my function?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function bgColor(id) {
  var divs = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('div'),
      colors = ['red','blue','green','orange', 'black', 'purple'];

  [].forEach.call(divs, function(d, index) {
    d.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: ' + colors[index % colors.length]);
  });
}

bgColor('box');
```

```css
#box div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <h3>box</h3>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is also  a nice one

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a solution https://jsfiddle.net/8rkceLv9/3/
You just select all divs inside `#box` and set them a background.
I don't see the point in array in array.